# prove $\{z_n\}$ converges where $z_n=f(z_{n-1})$

Tags: convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

Let $f : \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$, $f(z) = \frac{1}{2}z^2 + 1$, and $c = 1 + i$. Let $\{z_n\}$ be the sequence defined by iterating $f$ on some initial value $z_0 ∈ C$ (that is, $z_n = f(z_{n−1})$ for all $n \geq 1$).
(a) Prove that, if $\{z_n\}$ converges, it converges to $c$

I try to let $z_0=re^{ia}$ then get $z_1=\frac{1}{2}r^2e^{2ia}+1$ but $z_2$ will be a mess. if I put $z_0=x+iy$ it still does not work. So how to make it more sense to prove convergence.maybe just a hint of how to set the value of $z_0$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: What is $c$ doing in all this?

Comment: so we need to prove that (zn)converges to c which is 1+i or c with hat which means 1-i

Comment: If it converges, then its modulus must also converge to some value. Have you tried induction on n applied to the modulus?

Comment: By $z_0 \in C$, did you mean $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, or is $C$ some subset of $\mathbb{C}$.